# Setting div position using coordinates

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I'm having a web page (jsp) that included another jsp using

```
     <%@jsp:include ... %>
```

When I click on the second part (included page), getting the co-ordinates using:

```
    window.event.clientX 
    window.event.clientY
```

and storing into x and y respectively. Now I'm setting a div to visible at that mouse co-ordinates like,

```
    document.getElementById('division').style.top=x;
    document.getElementById('division').style.left=y;
```

as expected to display that div at the same spot where the mouse clicked. But the division is coming somewhere else.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Are you positioning your div as absolute or relative?

Comment: Does the div have any container div if not try to position it relative.

Comment: If relative, its position is not changing instead rendering in a constant position(actually where it is coded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top property is a string. Try `document.getElementById('division').style.top=x + 'px';`

I tried the following code and it worked fine for IE and Firefox. The onclick is for IE, the addEventListener is for compliant browsers.

```
<div id="clickMe" style="position: absolute; top: 10px;" onclick="myClick();">
    clickMe
</div>
<div id="division" style="position: absolute; top: 40px;">
    division
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickMe = document.getElementById('clickMe');
    clickMe.addEventListener('click', myClick, 'false');

    function myClick(e) {
        var evt = e || window.event; //windows.event is for IE
        var x = evt.clientX;
        var y = evt.clientY;            
        document.getElementById('division').style.top = y + 'px';
        document.getElementById('division').style.left = x + 'px';
    }
</script>
```